# Changing default shortcut for Spaces on a Macbook Pro with Snow Leapord?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, osx-spaces

I'm primarily a Linux user but my main home PC is a Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard. The concept of "Spaces" in a Mac is extremely important to how I utilize my development environments and I use this feature on Linux all the time.

I use Compiz Manager for Ubuntu which allows me to "Desktop Switch" and navigate all desktops using the Ctrl+Alt+Arrow keys to a particular desktop.

On a Mac, the process is similar, however, you're only given 3 non-customizable short-cuts: Option+Arrow, Ctrl+Arrow, and Alt+Arrow.

How can I change the keyboard shortcut to take Ctrl+Option? The keys would then fit my working style and it won't feel awkward to remember two sets of keyboard shortcuts.

Thanks!

Mahmoud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snow Leopard spaces allows you to customise the keys to switch between space.

Preferences->Expose/Spaces->Spaces shows a choice of one of Option+Arrow, Ctrl+Arrow, and Alt+Arrow but on the list box you can also hit cmd and this gives a choice of ctrl-option-arrow

Note this was done on a full keyboard so MacBook might not do this all.

Comment: Great answer Mark! Thanks so much, really appreciate that tip.

Answer (score 1):

[Hyperspaces](https://hyperspacesapp.com) enhances spaces with more functions / keyboard shortcuts offered and Ctrl-Option-arrow does work.
Plus, you can have a different background each space (up to 3 spaces for free; more if you pay) if you find that attractive - I find it useful.  (The free / for-pay limitation only applies to the number of spaces with distinct backgrounds; the app still works with more).

Comment: I'll take a look, but I was looking for something already built-in. Thanks again for the tip.